# Edit multiple tables with the same structure at the same time?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, attribute-table, plugins

does anyone know how to edit multiple tables at the same time? I have multiple .tab files and I want to change the order of the fields. Is there any way to do this for all of them at once. They all have identical table structures. I have both MapInfo and QGIS available to use.

Thanks, Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allan,
One way of doing this in MapInfo Pro is by using the MapBasic Window:

1: Open the MapBasic window thru Options > Show MapBasic window

2: Change the order of the column of one of your tables thru Table > Maintenance > Table Structure

Now notice that the MapBasic statement for reordering your columns has been added to the MapBasic window.

3a. Change the name of the table in the statement to match the next table and hit Enter. This will reorder the columns of that table, too.

3b. Or change the name of the table in the statement to "TableInfo(1,1)". This will reorder the columns of the first table in the list of tables kept by MapInfo Pro.

Note that when you reorder or change the table structure of a table, the table is currently put to the end of this list. You can use this to reorder the structure of several tables, simply by hitting Enter for this statement as many times as you have tables that must be reordered.